# How can I fix index out of range' error when generating a python code with Tkinter Designer from Figma?

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, figma

This is the error I'm getting on my shell when I use the credentials to generate a python code on Tkinter Desingner:

```
window_data = self.file_data["document"]["children"][0]["children"][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui.py", line 72, in btn_clicked
    designer.design()
  File "/home/carol/Tkinter-Designer/tkdesigner/designer.py", line 29, in design
    code = self.to_code()
  File "/home/carol/Tkinter-Designer/tkdesigner/designer.py", line 21, in to_code
```

The Figma file:
https://www.figma.com/file/Zadkbq5PwiqK15LjxlFyWn/login?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: have you tried debugging the issue by checking what each of those names refer to? like what does `self.file_data['document']['children']` contain? maybe that is an empty list?

Comment: this code was automatic generated by Tkinter-Designer I don't know where to look @Matiiss